# iFrame doesn't keep its height and width on rotation

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, rotation

I'm building a website previewer that should support rotations. My code works well until I rotate it:

[image: preview]

Here is a snippet:

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('ss4')

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
    document.getElementById('viewer').classList.add('rotation');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('viewer').classList.remove('rotation');
  }
})
```

```css
#viewer { 
  transition: all 0.5s; 
  max-width: 100%; 
  max-height: 100%; 
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 80px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
  transform: scale(0.6);
}

.size-select, .rotate-select { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: -100px; 
  left: -100px; 
  opacity: 0 
}

.size-select + label, .rotate-select + label { 
  position:fixed; 
  top: 10px; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 40px; 
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFF; 
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  display: inline-flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center; 
  color:  #807e7e;
}
.size-select + label svg, .rotate-select + label svg { 
  fill:  currentcolor;
}
.size-select:first-of-type + label, .rotate-select:first-of-type + label { 
  border-top-left-radius: 4px; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; 
}
.size-select:last-of-type + label, .rotate-select:last-of-type + label { 
  border-top-right-radius: 4px; 
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; 
}
.size-select:checked + label, .rotate-select:checked + label { 
  background: #8557dc; 
  color: #FFF;
  border-color: #8557dc;
}
.size1 + label { 
  left: calc(50% - 150px); 
  transform: translateX(-50px); 
}
.size2 + label { 
  left: calc(50% - 50px); 
  transform: translateX(-50px); 
}
.size3 + label { 
  left: calc(50% + 50px); 
  transform: translateX(-50px); 
}
.size4 + label { 
  left: calc(50% + 150px); 
  transform: translateX(-50px); 
}

.size1:checked ~ #viewer { 
  width: 375px; 
  height: 667px; 
  border-radius: 2.75rem;
  border-style: outset;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
}
.size2:checked ~ #viewer { 
  width: 1000px; 
  height: 672px;
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  border-style: outset;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
}
.size3:checked ~ #viewer { 
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.rotation {
  rotate: z -90deg;
}

.size1:checked ~ #viewer #iViewer { 
  border-radius: 1.75rem!important;
}
.size2:checked ~ #viewer  #iViewer { 
  border-radius: 0.25rem!important;
}
.size4:checked ~ #viewer #iViewer { 
  rotate: z 90deg;
  height: 100%!important; 
  width: 100%!important; 
  border-radius: 1.75rem!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview-wrapper" style="height: 100%!important; width: 100%!important;">
  
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="0" class="size-select size1" checked id="ss1">
    <label for="ss1" title="Small (eg phone)">
        <svg height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <path d="M17 1.01L7 1c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v18c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h10c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V3c0-1.1-.9-1.99-2-1.99zM17 19H7V5h10v14z"/>
        </svg>
    </label>
  
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="1" class="size-select size2" id="ss2">
    <label for="ss2" title="Medium (eg tablet)">
        <svg height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <path d="M21 4H3c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h18c1.1 0 1.99-.9 1.99-2L23 6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-2 14H5V6h14v12z"/>
        </svg>
    </label>
  
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="2" class="size-select size3" id="ss3">
    <label for="ss3" title="Large (eg desktop)">
        <svg height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <path d="M21 2H3c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h7v2H8v2h8v-2h-2v-2h7c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 14H3V4h18v12z"/>
        </svg>
    </label>
  
    <input type="checkbox" name="rotate" class="rotate-select size4" id="ss4">
    <label for="ss4" title="Rotate">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M7.5,21.5C4.25,19.94 1.91,16.76 1.55,13H0.05C0.56,19.16 5.71,24 12,24L12.66,23.97L8.85,20.16M14.83,21.19L2.81,9.17L9.17,2.81L21.19,14.83M10.23,1.75C9.64,1.16 8.69,1.16 8.11,1.75L1.75,8.11C1.16,8.7 1.16,9.65 1.75,10.23L13.77,22.25C14.36,22.84 15.31,22.84 15.89,22.25L22.25,15.89C22.84,15.3 22.84,14.35 22.25,13.77L10.23,1.75M16.5,2.5C19.75,4.07 22.09,7.24 22.45,11H23.95C23.44,4.84 18.29,0 12,0L11.34,0.03L15.15,3.84L16.5,2.5Z" />.
        </svg>
    </label>
  
    <div id='viewer' style="margin: auto">
        <iframe id="iViewer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" name='Viewer' src='https://www.nemenvisual.com/'></iframe>
    </div>
<div>
```

I'm not so sure why the `iFrame` doesn't respect the `height` and `width`. It only keeps the proper size if the `iFrame` is also rotated wrongly. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

**Update using Transform Origin:**

I thought of a second option, but it's not so reliable.

```js
var currentValue = 0;
function handleClick(myRadio) {
    currentValue = myRadio.value;
    
    if (currentValue == 2) {
      let iViewer = document.getElementById('iViewer');
      iViewer.style.height = `100%`;
      iViewer.style.width = `100%`;
      iViewer.style.transformOrigin = "";      
    }
}

const checkbox = document.getElementById('ss4')

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
        document.getElementById('viewer').classList.add('rotation');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('viewer').classList.remove('rotation');
    }
  
    let iViewer = document.getElementById('iViewer');

    let height = iViewer.offsetHeight;
    let width = iViewer.offsetWidth;
    let perHeight = 0;
    
    //I noticed this percentage 0.615 is the one I need to know to calculate to align it correctly
    perHeight = ((width * 0.615) * 100) / document.body.offsetHeight;

    if (event.currentTarget.checked && currentValue == 0) {
      iViewer.style.height = `${width}px`;
      iViewer.style.width = `${height}px`;
      iViewer.style.transformOrigin = `${perHeight}% 50%`;
    } else if (event.currentTarget.checked && currentValue == 1) {
      iViewer.style.height = `${width}px`;
      iViewer.style.width = `${height}px`;
      iViewer.style.transformOrigin = `${perHeight}% 50%`;
    } else {
      iViewer.style.height = `100%`;
      iViewer.style.width = `100%`;
      iViewer.style.transformOrigin = "";
    }
});
```

```css
#viewer { 
  transition: all 0.5s; 
  max-width: 100%; 
  max-height: 100%; 
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 80px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
  transform: scale(0.6);
}

.size-select, .rotate-select { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: -100px; 
  left: -100px; 
  opacity: 0 
}

.size-select + label, .rotate-select + label { 
  position:fixed; 
  top: 10px; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 40px; 
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFF; 
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  display: inline-flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center; 
  color:  #807e7e;
}
.size-select + label svg, .rotate-select + label svg { 
  fill:  currentcolor;
}
.size-select:first-of-type + label, .rotate-select:first-of-type + label { 
  border-top-left-radius: 4px; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; 
}
.size-select:last-of-type + label, .rotate-select:last-of-type + label { 
  border-top-right-radius: 4px; 
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; 
}
.size-select:checked + label, .rotate-select:checked + label { 
  background: #8557dc; 
  color: #FFF;
  border-color: #8557dc;
}
.size1 + label { 
  left: calc(50% - 150px); 
  transform: translateX(-50px); 
}
.size2 + label { 
  left: calc(50% - 50px); 
  transform: translateX(-50px); 
}
.size3 + label { 
  left: calc(50% + 50px); 
  transform: translateX(-50px); 
}
.size4 + label { 
  left: calc(50% + 150px); 
  transform: translateX(-50px); 
}

.size1:checked ~ #viewer { 
  width: 375px; 
  height: 667px; 
  border-radius: 2.75rem;
  border-style: outset;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
}
.size2:checked ~ #viewer { 
  width: 1000px; 
  height: 672px;
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  border-style: outset;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
}
.size3:checked ~ #viewer { 
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.rotation {
  rotate: z -90deg;
}

#iViewer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.size1:checked ~ #viewer #iViewer { 
  border-radius: 1.75rem!important;
}
.size2:checked ~ #viewer  #iViewer { 
  border-radius: 0.25rem!important;
}
.size4:checked ~ #viewer #iViewer { 
  rotate: z 90deg;
}

.size1-tablet + label { 
  left: calc(50% - 100px); 
  transform: translateX(-50px); 
}
.size3-tablet + label { 
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translateX(-50px); 
}
.size4-tablet + label { 
  left: calc(50% + 100px); 
  transform: translateX(-50px); 
}

.size1-tablet:checked ~ #viewer { 
  width: 375px; 
  height: 667px; 
  border-radius: 2.75rem;
  border-style: outset;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
}
.size3-tablet:checked ~ #viewer { 
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.size1-tablet:checked ~ #viewer #iViewer { 
  border-radius: 1.75rem!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="preview-wrapper" style="height: 100%!important; width: 100%!important;">
  
    <input type="radio" name="size" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="0" class="size-select size1" checked id="ss1">
    <label for="ss1" title="Small (eg phone)">
        <svg height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <path d="M17 1.01L7 1c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v18c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h10c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V3c0-1.1-.9-1.99-2-1.99zM17 19H7V5h10v14z"/>
        </svg>
    </label>
  
    <input type="radio" name="size" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="1" class="size-select size2" id="ss2">
    <label for="ss2" title="Medium (eg tablet)">
        <svg height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <path d="M21 4H3c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h18c1.1 0 1.99-.9 1.99-2L23 6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-2 14H5V6h14v12z"/>
        </svg>
    </label>
  
    <input type="radio" name="size" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="2" class="size-select size3" id="ss3">
    <label for="ss3" title="Large (eg desktop)">
        <svg height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <path d="M21 2H3c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v12c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h7v2H8v2h8v-2h-2v-2h7c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 14H3V4h18v12z"/>
        </svg>
    </label>
  
    <input type="checkbox" name="rotate" class="rotate-select size4" id="ss4">
    <label for="ss4" title="Rotate">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M7.5,21.5C4.25,19.94 1.91,16.76 1.55,13H0.05C0.56,19.16 5.71,24 12,24L12.66,23.97L8.85,20.16M14.83,21.19L2.81,9.17L9.17,2.81L21.19,14.83M10.23,1.75C9.64,1.16 8.69,1.16 8.11,1.75L1.75,8.11C1.16,8.7 1.16,9.65 1.75,10.23L13.77,22.25C14.36,22.84 15.31,22.84 15.89,22.25L22.25,15.89C22.84,15.3 22.84,14.35 22.25,13.77L10.23,1.75M16.5,2.5C19.75,4.07 22.09,7.24 22.45,11H23.95C23.44,4.84 18.29,0 12,0L11.34,0.03L15.15,3.84L16.5,2.5Z" />.
        </svg>
    </label>
  
    <div id='viewer' style="margin: auto">
        <iframe id="iViewer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" name='Viewer' src='https://www.nemenvisual.com/'></iframe>
    </div>
<div>
```

In this second option, in my current screen, the alignment is perfect:

[image: preview 2]

But it can show the wrong alignment if the screen changes since it relies on this section:

[image: preview 3]

```js
let iViewer = document.getElementById('iViewer');

let height = iViewer.offsetHeight;
let width = iViewer.offsetWidth;
let perHeight = 0;

//I noticed this percentage 0.615 is the one I need to know to calculate to align it correctly
perHeight = ((width * 0.615) * 100) / document.body.offsetHeight;

if (event.currentTarget.checked && currentValue == 0) {
  iViewer.style.height = `${width}px`;
  iViewer.style.width = `${height}px`;
  iViewer.style.transformOrigin = `${perHeight}% 50%`;
} else if (event.currentTarget.checked && currentValue == 1) {
  iViewer.style.height = `${width}px`;
  iViewer.style.width = `${height}px`;
  iViewer.style.transformOrigin = `${perHeight}% 50%`;
} else {
  iViewer.style.height = `100%`;
  iViewer.style.width = `100%`;
  iViewer.style.transformOrigin = "";
}
```

In the `` iViewer.style.transformOrigin = `${perHeight}% 50%`; `` I have to do the configuration, but for the accurate starting left location I got it like this:

```js
let width = iViewer.offsetWidth;
let perHeight = 0;

//I noticed this percentage 0.615 is the one I need to know to calculate to align it correctly
perHeight = ((width * 0.615) * 100) / document.body.offsetHeight;
```

But the main issue is the `0.615` percentage, I'm not so sure how to calculate on demand. Any idea what would be the best way to get it? I thought it was `0.6` since it would be the same value as the same as `transform: scale(0.6)`, but in my current screen didn't work, the `0.6` was closed, but it wasn't perfect, and in other screens can be bigger or smaller.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need any JS for this at all - just use `vw` and `vh` units... also, using `transform:` will create a new stacking-context which may be undesirable.

Comment: Hi @Dai, there are reasons behind the JS. The previewer is for an Angular app. Any idea, how can I fix the rotation? The rest is working as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this just because you rotate the device wrapper _and_ the device content 90deg? You can see both animate, which would get the result you wanted. However, in order to make your iframe really go landscape, you need to change its size and not its rotation, as you always want it rotated correctly? So these two 90deg angles are fine, just resize the width and height of the iframe?

Comment: Hi @somethinghere, I tried to change the size and the location goes wrongly. Any suggestion?

Comment: The problem is that you are relying on % to determine the size, which obviously won't work because the rotated element, by default, is still portrait. I'm not sure if a resize observer detects transforms, that might be an option? You're going to have to find a way to make your iframe adjust to the correct size.

Comment: Hi @somethinghere, I provided an alternative using **Transform Origin**, but then, I get other bugs. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any advice on how to fix it @Dai? I provided a new experiment that I did.